# error when trying to overload << operator and using friend function

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload **<<** operator and using friend function.
Below code chunk works just fine.

```
template <class T>
class Mystack{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Mystack<T> const& d)
    {
        d.print(s);
        return s;
    } 
};
```

Since it is friend function I would obviously want to define it outside the class without using scope resolution operator. But when I try that I get error.

```
template <class T>
class Mystack{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Mystack<T> const& d); 
};
template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Mystack<T> const& d)
{
    d.print(s);
    return s;
}
```

Below is the code snippet for main

```
Mystack<int> intstack;
std::cout << intstack;
```

**ERROR** : Unresolved extrernal symbol.

P.S: Its not the complete running code. Just a sample. Kindly bear.

Comment: `class sample{` shouldnt that be `class Mystack`?

Comment: When templates are involved, just put everything in the header file. It's not worth the headache.

Comment: @NeilKirk I get OP's error and everything is in one file [see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/849e468d61d0d8d6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Mystack<T> const& d);
```

declares and befriends a non-template `operator<<` function. So `Mystack<int>` would have as its friend a non-template function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Mystack<int> const& d);`, etc.

```
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Mystack<T> const& d)
{
    d.print(s);
    return s;
}
```

defines an `operator<<` function template.

The two are not the same. When you write `std::cout << intstack;`, the overload resolution rules resolve it to the non-template `operator<<` function you declared, but it isn't defined, so you get a linker error.

There's no way to define a non-template function for every instantiation of a class template outside the class template. You can, however, befriend a specialization of your `operator<<` function template:

```
// forward declarations
template <class T>
class Mystack;
template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Mystack<T> const& d);

template <class T>
class Mystack
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <T>(std::ostream& s, Mystack<T> const& d); 
//                                  ^^^
};
```

or befriend every specialization of the function template, which is worse from an encapsulation point of view (since, e.g., `operator<< <int>` would be a friend of `Mystack<float>`):

```
template <class T>
class Mystack
{
public:
    template <class U>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Mystack<U> const& d);
};
```

or just define the friend function inside the class.

Comment: what if I remove `template <class T>` from the function. then also I get the error.

Comment: @tanz As in, just `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Mystack<T> const& d)`? Then you can't use `T`.

Comment: @T.C. Would you elaborate which way is the best way to go with? I mean what is the best practice for this kind of situation (e.g. friending an operator overload for a class template ...). Should we go with inside-the-class definition or the first way you mentioned (the second way is obviously dangerous).